# jquery in tablesorter and row checker

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a table that uses jquery tablesorter. I wanted to expand its functionality by including jquery code that when clicked on any part of a given row it would check a checkbox in that row and also it would change the row background color simulating that the row is selected.

In a standalone sample the code for checking the checkbox works fine, but as soon as I apply the tablesorter CSS, it doesn't change the row background. It still checks the box, I just can't make it simulate selection of the row by changing its background color.

Here is the code and two sample links:

Doesn't work with tablesorter: http://www.laredo.edu/hb2504/table.php
Works as standalone: http://www.laredo.edu/hb2504/table2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>HB2504 - Syllabi</title>


    <!-- --><link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/blue/style.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen" /> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {      





////////////////////////////////////////////////  function for instructional  //////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // call the tablesorter plugin
  $("#tablesorter-demo").tablesorter({
  // Raul uncomment this to start sort automatically first //sortList:[[0,0]], 
  widgets: ['zebra'],
   theme : 'blue',

    dateFormat : "mmddyyyy", // set the default date format

    // or to change the format for specific columns, add the dateFormat to the headers option:
    headers: {
      //3: { sorter: "shortDate" } //, dateFormat will parsed as the default above
      // 1: { sorter: "shortDate", dateFormat: "ddmmyyyy" }, // set day first format; set using class names
      // 2: { sorter: "shortDate", dateFormat: "yyyymmdd" }  // set year first format; set using data attributes (jQuery data)
    }


  });
////////////////////////////////////////////////  function for instructional  //////////////////////////////////////////////////




    }); 

    </script>


    <style type="text/css">

    body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; /* !!! */
}

.centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1024px;
}
    </style>




  <style type="text/css">
    td {
    border: 0px solid;
    }

    .syllabus td{
    border: 1px solid;  
     margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    }

  </style>

    <style type='text/css'>

.highlight_row {
    background: #eee;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tablesorter tr').click(function (event) {
        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
        }
    });

    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight_row");
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("highlight_row");
        }
    });
});

</script>



</head>

<body>
<table style="text-align:left;padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;width:1024px;" id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>CH</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
        <th>3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>




  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=checkbox></td>
        <td>Anabel</td>
        <td>Beto</td>
        <td>Carmen</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type=checkbox></td>
        <td>Daniel</td>
        <td>Ernesto</td>
        <td>Fernando</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>


</table>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, which was modified from the ["forms" demo](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/wiki#more-demos) to allow clicking on the row to check the box - [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/4218/).

```
// checkbox parser
$.tablesorter.addParser( {
    id: 'checkbox',
    is: function( s ) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function( s, table, cell ) {
        var $c = $( cell ).find( 'input' );
        return $c.length ? $c.is( ':checked' ) ? 1 : 2 : s;
    },
    type: 'numeric'
});

$( function() {
    // using .on() which requires jQuery 1.7+
    $( 'table' ).on( 'tablesorter-initialized', function() {

        // class name to add on tr when checkbox is checked
        var highlightClass = 'checked',
        // resort the table after the checkbox is modified?
        resort = true,
        // if a server side database needs to be updated, do it here
        serverCallback = function( table, inputElement ) {},

        $table = $( this ),
        c = this.config,
        wo = c && c.widgetOptions,
        // include sticky header checkbox; if installed
        $sticky = c && wo.$sticky || '',
        doChecky = function( c, col ) {
            $table
                .children( 'tbody' )
                .children( 'tr:visible' )
                .children( 'td:nth-child( ' + ( parseInt( col, 10 ) + 1 ) + ' )' )
                .find( 'input' )
                .each( function() {
                    this.checked = c;
                    $( this ).trigger( 'change' );
                });
        };

        $table
            .children( 'tbody' )
            .on( 'click', 'tr', function() {
                // clicking on row, toggles the checkbox in first column
                $(this).children('td:first').find('input[type=checkbox]')
                    .prop('checked', function(i, val) {
                        return !val;
                    })
                    // trigger a change so tablesorter will update the value
                    .trigger('change');
            })
            .end()
            .on( 'change', 'input', function() {
                // ignore change if updating all rows
                if ( $table[0].ignoreChange ) { return; }
                var col, $this = $( this );
                $this.closest( 'tr' ).toggleClass( highlightClass, this.checked );
                $this.trigger( 'updateCell', [ $this.closest( 'td' ), resort ] );
                // if your server side database needs more parameters, add them here sent to the callback
                serverCallback( $table[0], this );
                // uncheck header if any checkboxes are unchecked
                if ( !this.checked ) {
                    $table.add( $sticky ).find( 'thead input' ).prop( 'checked', false );
                }
            })
            .end()
            .add( $sticky )
            .find( 'thead input' )
            // Click on checkbox in table header to toggle all inputs
            .on( 'change', function() {
                // prevent updateCell for every cell
                $table[0].ignoreChange = true;
                var c = this.checked,
                    col = $( this ).closest( 'th' ).attr( 'data-column' );
                doChecky( c, col );
                // update main & sticky header
                $table.add( $sticky ).find( 'th[data-column=' + col + '] input' ).prop( 'checked', c );
                $table.children( 'tbody' ).children( 'tr:visible' ).toggleClass( highlightClass, c );
                // update all at once
                $table[0].ignoreChange = false;
                $table.trigger( 'update', [ resort ] );
            })
            .on( 'mouseup', function() {
                return false;
            });

    });
});


$(function(){
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blackice',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'stickyHeaders'],
        headers: {
            0: { sorter: 'checkbox' }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: To answer your question about the row you clicked on apparently not getting highlighted, this is because after clicking on the row, the plugin resorts the table, so the row moves. Change the `resort` variable in the code to `false` to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In response to Answer 1.

That script works great, although there with minor modifications. I used the code in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/165/) which is very similar to the one your provided. This one did the opposite, which is to highlight the row upon the checkbox being checked.

The one you provided checked the box upon the row being clicked, but neither code did both so I kind of mixed them so that the checkbox got checked and the row highlighted upon row click or upon checkbox checked.

Below is the complete code and a working demo:

[Demo](http://www.laredo.edu/hb2504/table3_1.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<script>
function clearForms()
{
  var i;
  for (i = 0; (i < document.forms.length); i++) {
    document.forms[i].reset();
  }
}
</script>





  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>




    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorterblack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/black/black.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen" /> 


  <style type='text/css'>


table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd.checked td {
    background: #8080c0;
    color: #fff;
}
table.tablesorter tbody tr.even.checked td {
    background: #a0a0e0;
    color: #fff;
}

.spacer { height: 1000px; }

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff; 
}
  </style>

</head>
<body onLoad="clearForms()" onUnload="clearForms()">

<form method=POST action="table3php.php">
<table class="tablesorter">

     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th></th>
             <th>Course</th>
             <th>Course Title</th>
            <!-- <th>Last Name</th>
             <th>First Name</th> -->
         </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody>
<tr>

<td><input type=checkbox name=course[] value=GOVT2305M01></td>

<td>GOVT2305M01</td>

<td>Federal Government </td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><input type=checkbox name=course[] value=GOVT2306M07></td>

<td>GOVT2306M07</td>

<td>Texas Government </td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><input type=checkbox name=course[] value=GOVT2305M04></td>

<td>GOVT2305M04</td>

<td>Federal Government </td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><input type=checkbox name=course[] value=GOVT2306M01></td>

<td>GOVT2306M01</td>

<td>Texas Government </td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><input type=checkbox name=course[] value=GOVT2305M03></td>

<td>GOVT2305M03</td>

<td>Federal Government </td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><input type=checkbox name=course[] value=GOVT2305M02></td>

<td>GOVT2305M02</td>

<td>Federal Government </td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><input type=checkbox name=course[] value=GOVT2306E01></td>

<td>GOVT2306E01</td>

<td>Texas Government </td>

</tr>

     </tbody>



</table>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div class="spacer"></div>



<script type='text/javascript'>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tablesorter tr').click(function(event) {
        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
        }
    });
});

// add parser through the tablesorter addParser method
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'checkbox',
    is: function(s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
        var $t = $(table), $c = $(cell), c,

        // column containing all of the checkboxes (zero-based index)
        columnWithCheckboxes = 0,
        // resort the table after the checkbox status has changed
        resort = false;

        if (!$t.hasClass('hasCheckbox')) {
            $t
            .addClass('hasCheckbox')
            // make checkbox in header set all others
            .find('thead th:eq(' + columnWithCheckboxes + ') input[type=checkbox]')
            .bind('change', function(){
                c = this.checked;
                $t.find('tbody tr td:nth-child(' + (columnWithCheckboxes + 1) + ') input').each(function(){
                  this.checked = c;
                  $(this).trigger('change');
                });
            })
            .bind('mouseup', function(){
                return false;
            });
            $t.find('tbody tr').each(function(){
                $(this).find('td:eq(' + columnWithCheckboxes + ')').find('input[type=checkbox]').bind('change', function(){
                    $t.trigger('updateCell', [$(this).closest('td')[0], resort]);
                });
            });
        }
        // return 1 for true, 2 for false, so true sorts before false
        c = ($c.find('input[type=checkbox]')[0].checked) ? 1 : 2;
        $c.closest('tr')[ c === 1 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]('checked');
        return c;
    },
    type: 'numeric'
});

$(function() {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blackice',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'stickyHeaders'],
        headers: {
            0: {
                sorter: 'checkbox'
            }
        }
    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```